# Understanding Salesforce ERD

Tags: standard-objects, lookup-filter, data-model

I was wondering if someone here could please help me understand a Salesforce ERD.
To be completely honest, this diagram is from a Superbadge, however I think it's a basic enough question of concepts that won't be against Trailhead rules to ask it here. In case it's not, please let me know and I will remove the question.

[image]

Here is the part of the diagram in question.
My understanding is the following:
The Account object has two record types, a "Business Account" which represents Venues Streaming Services and Vendors, and a "Person Account", which represents only Fans.
The Contact object has two record types as well, a "Business Account", which can represent an Agent, a Venue Personeel and a Producer and a "Person Contact" which represent a Fan only.
The way I'm relating these two objects is by relying in the standard lookup relationship Contact has to Account, and in order to limit that a Business Contact can only be related to a Business Account and that a Person Contact can only be related to a Person Account is by using required lookup filters, where I'm using the record type of the contact to determine which Account record types will be available for selection

[image]

Where I'm not sure on how to proceed is on how to limit the user to relate the Person Account only to one Person Contact. The only solution I have been able to find to model this one-to-one relationship is by using a formula field on the parent object which shows the number of children and reference in the same lookup filter to only show Person Account which are not yet related to any Person Contact.
I'm not sure, however, if this is the recommended approach to model this kind of relationship.

Comment: I assume this question/superbadge is not actually referring to the "Person Accounts" feature which combines account & contact data into a single record? (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_person.htm&type=5). It is instead just using a business account record type called "Person Account"? It's hard to say, because Salesforce's documentation says any time they are referring to the Person Account feature they will specifically use the term "Person Accounts" which is the term used in the diagram. Is this your diagram, or a diagram from trailhead?

Comment: Hi Morgan. The diagram is directly from the trailhead. However I don't think they're referring to the PersonAccount object, as the legend of the diagram says that the Continuous line boxes are objects and the dashed line are record types. But it actually sound like a valid approach now that you mention it, even though it doesn't seems to be represented in the diagram

Comment: https://architect.salesforce.com/diagrams/framework/data-model-notation is a good read.  Also, google "logical vs physical data model"

Comment: I recommend going to [Trailhead Help](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help) to 1) check the forum to see if there's any discussion about this and 2) open a case with SF and ask them to clarify if this is indeed the special Person Account feature.